# Where to start in finding users in a radius from me

Tags: ios, gps, geolocation

Where to start to write app to have users find each other based on their defined location?

I'm looking for something similar to the tinder search for people in a specific location.

Would I be using map points in mapkit or GPS locations and if so, can anyone point me towards an example of how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need backend-based solution to store and query user locations.
You can go with Parse.com tutorial [Anywall](https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall). If you need more rapid solution you can look onto [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) or your own backend.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I was actually about to check out Anywell. That's probably going to give me what I need